# Seeking Empirical Data Sources Relevant for an Alternative Gravity Theory

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, space-expansion, data, modified-gravity

I am currently developing an alternative theory of gravity and am in need of empirical data sources that could assist in evaluating the potential validity and implications of this theory. This model, at a high conceptual level, is predicated on the idea that mass attracts space itself, thereby indirectly influencing the movement and interaction of other masses in that space.

This concept gives rise to a few interesting implications:

1. Different densities of space: In this theory, space itself has different densities, with each density having potentially unique quantum effects.
2. Gravity inversion: At a certain distance and space density, gravity is predicted to "flip", causing two masses to repel rather than attract each other. This could potentially explain the observed expansion of the universe.
3. Non-uniform expansion in multi-galactic systems:  In systems with differing numbers of galaxies (specifically comparing a three-galaxy system to a two-galaxy system), where the galaxies are relatively close to each other compared to other galaxies yet far enough apart to experience cosmic expansion, this model anticipates a distinct behaviour of expansion. This contrasts with the predictions of standard cosmological models, which suggest a uniform expansion everywhere, regardless of whether the system consists of two or three galaxies.

Given these implications, I am looking for any observational data or experimental results that might be relevant for my theory. Specifically, I am interested in:

- Observations related to the measurement of cosmic expansion in multi-galactic systems.
- Data on quantum effects that could potentially vary with the "density" of space (this may be challenging given the unconventional premise, but any leads are appreciated).
- Any documented instances of gravity behaving counter-intuitively, or observations suggesting that gravity might "flip" under certain conditions.

I understand that this is a speculative theory and requires rigorous mathematical formalism and empirical testing. My primary aim at the moment is to identify relevant data sources that I could use to begin evaluating the theory and potentially guiding its further development. Any guidance on how to approach this, or references to specific datasets or experiments, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *multi-galactic systems* Does the observable universe qualify? It’s multi-galactic, and there is plenty of data on the expansion of the universe.

Comment: Since personal theories are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, I suggest editing out all references to your personal theory, and just asking about data.

Comment: *gravity behaving counter-intuitively* Are you aware that in the current cosmological model, the expansion of the universe stopped decelerating and started accelerating, and that this model was constructed based on observations?

Comment: 1) is already in general relativity since the volume of a heavy sphere is larger than the volume of a light sphere with the same circumference and surface area.

Comment: Analyzing noisy data (like astronomical observations) that you didn't generate yourself (or as part of a collaboration) is an almost hopeless enterprise. You will mostly fall into the mousetraps that your own mistaken beliefs about the way the data was collected will set up for you. I believe that recently even happened to Penrose, who should know better. There seems to be a group of people now who are even suggesting that galactic rotation curves are basically unreliable because of the biases in their estimation from spectral data.

Answer (score 2):

There's some old data on [falling bodies](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Ejtc5/238/materials/Galileo-from-Statistical-Sleuth.pdf) and [orbital motion](http://www.pafko.com/tycho/observe.html) that may be relevant too. If you can reproduce those, you'll already be ahead of most of the competition...